# Php session ecrypted. How to avoid?

Tags: php, session, encryption, serialization

I want to remove session files when a admin user deactivate other user. On localhost the content of session files is only serialized, so I can identify the deactivated user and delete the file. But on production server it's encrypted. 
I suppose it should be a php.ini configuration. Can anyone tell me how to avoid it to be encrypted?

Local session file content:

```
 a:0:{}__flash|a:0:{}__id|i:18;txt_ex|i:0;txt_eq|i:0;txt_te|i:0;txt_ce|i:0;id_usuario|i:18;
```

Production session file content:

```
TPi-MpcCX-I5co0vHPmIKOXSTNXPH3JoRJ5JsbsfgEjBcfiU60tnfSU3lEnQ1X6cyWGehK5W0QAvYhityt5xnYdL5o5YIGO-B8IlnkeycPrg1B94pf9xnut6tiVDgoowhvLZFnRLZG4j5CfJYTFcjA..
```

Comment: The content does not look encrypted, encryption would have many non-character bytes. It is probably some kind of encoding or at least an encoding on top of encryption. Is the "Production session file content" complete in the question or is it just a portion?

Comment: Please fix your title spelling: when you write _ecrypted_, do you mean "decrypted" or "encrypted"?